# Dell SCCM 2012 Integration and deployment packs - Do they support Windows Server 2012 yet?

Tags: dell-poweredge, windows-server-2012, sccm, dell-openmanage

I am looking to migrate my dev SCCM 2012 SP 1 install from Windows Server 2008 R2 to Windows Server 2012.  I have been looking at the documentation for the Dell integration packs and want to incorporate this into my environment.

http://en.community.dell.com/dell-blogs/software/b/software/archive/2012/04/02/dellopenmanageintegrationsuiteformicrosoftsystemcenter.aspx

http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/555/DriverDetails?driverId=85VWM

http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/software/smddp/2_0/en/itg/itg.pdf

http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/b/techcenter/archive/2012/07/31/dell-client-integration-pack-for-ms-configuration-manager-2012-is-now-available.aspx

However it doesn't look like, according to this documentation, the Dell integration packs will run on/support Windows Server 2012 yet.  Has anyone tried to install any of this stuff into SCCM 2012 SP1 running on Server 2012?  Is the documentation lagging behind real world or is this not supported yet?

EDIT:  Updated to reflect I actually have SP1 up and running.  More so asking about the Dell products.

Answer (score 3):

You will want to get your hands on System Center 2012 SP1 which fully supports Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Sorry.  I updated to reflect that I had SP1 already.  Really asking about the functionality of the Dell products on Server 2012, not SCCM.

Comment: Gotcha.  Misunderstood the question and thought it was related directly to System Center 2012 only.  I will ask around as well.

Answer (score 0):

SCCM 2012 is not yet supported for installation on Server 2012.  It will [reportedly] be supported with the release of SP1 for SCCM 2012.  ([The beta SP1 for SCCM 2012 is available](http://blogs.technet.com/b/server-cloud/archive/2012/09/10/system-center-2012-configuration-manager-sp1-beta-and-windows-intune-update.aspx) for download, [if you wish to try that out](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=34607), but I wouldn't roll it to production until the RTM version of the Service Pack is made available.)

Comment: Sorry. I updated to reflect that I had SP1 already. Really asking about the functionality of the Dell products on Server 2012, not SCCM.